# Is it possible to use if..else statment inside for loop condition?

Tags: javascript, loops

```js
for(var i = n1; 
    if(n3>0){i<=n2} 
    else if(n3<0){i>=n2} 
    else{window.alert('error')}; 
    i += n3){
   nArr.push(i);
}
```

This is code i want to run.. somehow.. i want to do range function that writes from-to numbers with step into array.. i accomplished to do it in positive way but when i want negative i'd like only to invert "i<=n2" sign to "i>=n2" and not writing another loop.. is this possible?

Thanks in advance,
chiff :)

Comment: Do share _input-data_ and _expected-output_

Comment: For loop has its syntax, you can't change the syntax

Comment: @GulmuhammadAkbari Its syntax is quite flexible, though ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can combine your statements like this:

```
for(var i = n1; n3>0 && i<=n2 || n3<0 && i>=n2; i += n3){
      nArr.push(i);
}
```

but I wouldn't recommend that for the sake of readability

also, be advised that you are checking `n3` condition on every loop iteration, which is not good as it could be done only once

Comment: thats what i've been looking for.. but ye you are right that check is unnecessary.. so is it better to make one comparision before that loop and write loop two times with two different conditions?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you're trying to do like this:

```
if (n3 === 0) {
    // show error
    return;
}

for(var i = n1; n3 > 0 && i < n2 || n3 < 0 && i >= n2; i += n3) {
    nArr.push(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`if` in JS isn't an expression, so I guess nope. An IIFE could do the trick, though:

```js
var a = 5;
for (var i = 0; (function() {
  if (a > 3)
    return i < 2;
  else
    return i < 4;
})(); i++) {
  document.write(i);
}
```

You could make it vastly cleaner and clearer by putting the loop inside of the `if`, though.

Comment: thank you too this is answer too :) this is the way i wanted to accomplish this problem

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not use an if-else statement within the body of a for loop. Especially if it contains an `alert()` window.

In your particular case it would be better to use a while statement.

```
var i = n1;
while ((n3 > 0 && i <= n2) || (n3 < 0 && i >= n2)) {
  nArr.push(i);
  i += n3;
}
```

I do not know exactly what you want to achieve but this is a jist of it.